# Make SVG chart that resizes but doesn't stretch the text

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to fill the centre of a webpage with a D3 generated chart that resizes to fit the space, but I can't stop it from stretching the text that I use for points and the axes labels. I see the SVG attribute *vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"* and that looks great for the lines on the chart, but the text keeps the aspect ratio of the whole chart so when the chart really wide, so is the text.

I'd like to avoid redrawing the whole chart every time the container changes size because it'd flicker and suck CPU, though I don't expect anyone will be sitting there resizing it constantly. And I'd like the chart to really fill the space, not just maintain its aspect ratio. That makes the text look the right shape, but grows and shrinks along with the chart.

Examples:

[image: Really wide chart]

[image: really tall chart]

This is a cut down version of the svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <path class="gridded-line" fill="none" stroke="steelblue" stroke-width="1" d="M0,23.58L15.278,12.217L35.417,59.194L100,20.281"/>
  <rect width="20" height="5" fill="none" transform="translate(35, 40)" style="stroke: rgb(71, 85, 210); stroke-width: 0.5; opacity: 1;"/>
  <text class="tooltip-text" fill="#4755D2" transform="translate(35, 40)" style="font-size: 2px; opacity: 1;">
    <tspan x="2" y="1.1em">292.93</tspan>
    <tspan x="2" y="2.1em">Thu Feb 01 2024</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: As the text elements are svg they will be scaled as well. I would be surprised if there would be a native solution countering the change of aspect ratio. You could try foreignObject and use an HTML DIV element instead of SVGTEXT. Maybe that works.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Comment: I understand the text is just a tooltip that lights up when the mouse passes over. In this case, you may use am external html element for the tooltip

Comment: I think foreignObject is a good solution for the tooltip but it would probably be impractical for the axes labels

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? Then I have a look at it.

Comment: @wasserholz I've added sample code now

Comment: could you provide also the d3.js code?